# NGINX Amazon EC2 keeps loading through 80 port is allowed

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to host ubuntu 18.4 server on aws ec2 instance.
[image: Here is my security group allowed port]]
Though I've allowed 80 port but when i tryto see on browser using my public ip it wont loading but it suppose to show nginx welcome screen.

`netstat -tuanp | grep 80`

output

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16912/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      16912/nginx: master
```

My nginx is running perfectly . Here is the status
[image: nginx status here]

My browser showing:

> This site can’t be reached `my_public_ip` took too long to respond.

Please Help!

Comment: Have you checked the subnet is public , meaning the routing table associated with the subnet which this machine has launched in has igw and also Network ACL allows traffic ?

Comment: Network ACL 
`Rule #|  Type        | Protocol |Port Range/ ICMP Type |Source | Allow / Deny
100      | ALL Traffic |ALL  |           ALL               0.0.0.0/0               ALLOW
*     | ALL Traffic |ALL  |           ALL               0.0.0.0/0               ALLOW `

Comment: I hope you opened the 80 port into 0.0.0.0:0.

Comment: Yes I opened 80 port